# Get element from Word Online webpage into Javascript for modification via Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, dom, html

I've been trying to modify a menu entry in the menu on Word Online document view for a few hours now, but everything I've been trying (getElementById, getElementsByClass, getElementsByTagName etc) doesn't seem to work. I even tried to use the XPath example available on this site.

Here's an example [link](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=4EB074721AF882B8!123&ithint=file%2Cdocx&app=Word&authkey=!AB5bNUMD3O6Lj_k) to try.

And here's what I'm trying to get done (just set the display property to none for a menu item)

```
document.getElementById("faSaveAs-Menu32").style.display = "none";
```

Could somebody please point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: I can post other failed attempts (they're too many) if they help in any way. 
I posted just the simple code above as it conveys what I'm trying to achieve and also what exactly fails to work.

Comment: Ok so after a lot of headache and research I now know what was the problem. IFrames. The particular element I'm trying to modify resides inside an iframe and I can't access it via simple javascript.
Is there some workaround available to userscripts to solve this issue?